# CS50 Week 4 Blur Filter, have blurred image but check50 values wrong

Tags: c, cs50

I have problems with my check50, I'm wondering if what I'm doing is actually getting the correct boxes.

the goal for blurring is to get all of the grey boxes colors and average them

for each pixel, if the pixel is not on the first row, I know I can have top boxes. If the pixel is not on the bottom row, I know I can have bottom boxes. Same logic with the edges to.

[image]

but there also cases where a pixel is in a corner or at a edge

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE arrayCopy[height][width]; 
    memcpy(arrayCopy, image, sizeof arrayCopy);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int totalRed = 0;
            int totalBlue = 0;
            int totalGreen = 0; 
            
            if (!(w == 0))
            {
                int leftBoxRed = arrayCopy[i][w-1].rgbtRed;
                int leftBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i][w-1].rgbtBlue;
                int leftBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i][w-1].rgbtGreen;
                
                totalRed = totalRed + leftBoxRed;
                totalBlue = totalBlue + leftBoxBlue;
                totalGreen = totalGreen + leftBoxGreen;
                counter++; 

                //printf("%i\n", leftBoxRed);
            }

            if (!(w == width-1))
            {
                int rightBoxRed = arrayCopy[i][w+1].rgbtRed;
                int rightBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i][w+1].rgbtBlue;
                int rightBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i][w+1].rgbtGreen;
                
                totalRed = totalRed + rightBoxRed; 
                totalBlue = totalBlue + rightBoxBlue;
                totalGreen = totalGreen + rightBoxGreen;
                counter++;
            }

            if (!(i == 0))
            {
                if (!(w == 0))
                {
                    int leftTopBoxRed = arrayCopy[i-1][w-1].rgbtRed;
                    int leftTopBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i-1][w-1].rgbtBlue;
                    int leftTopBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i-1][w-1].rgbtGreen; 
                    
                    totalRed = totalRed + leftTopBoxRed; 
                    totalBlue = totalBlue + leftTopBoxBlue;
                    totalGreen = totalGreen + leftTopBoxGreen;
                    counter++; 
                }
                
                if (!(w == width - 1))
                {
                    int rightTopBoxRed = arrayCopy[i-1][w+1].rgbtRed;
                    int rightTopBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i-1][w+1].rgbtBlue;
                    int rightTopBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i-1][w+1].rgbtGreen; 
                    
                    totalRed = totalRed + rightTopBoxRed; 
                    totalBlue = totalBlue + rightTopBoxBlue;
                    totalGreen = totalGreen + rightTopBoxGreen; 
                    counter++;
                }
                
                int topBoxRed = arrayCopy[i-1][w].rgbtRed;
                int topBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i-1][w].rgbtBlue;
                int topBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i-1][w].rgbtGreen;
                
                totalRed = totalRed + topBoxRed; 
                totalBlue = totalBlue + topBoxBlue; 
                totalGreen = totalGreen + topBoxGreen;
                counter++; 
            }

            if (!(i == height-1))
            {
                
                if (!(w == 0))
                {
                    int leftBottomBoxRed = arrayCopy[i+1][w-1].rgbtRed;
                    int leftBottomBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i+1][w-1].rgbtBlue;
                    int leftBottomBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i+1][w-1].rgbtGreen;
                    
                    totalRed = totalRed + leftBottomBoxRed; 
                    totalBlue = totalBlue + leftBottomBoxBlue;
                    totalGreen = totalGreen + leftBottomBoxGreen; 
                    counter++;
                }
                
                if (!(w == width - 1))
                {
                    int rightBottomBoxRed = arrayCopy[i+1][w+1].rgbtRed;
                    int rightBottomBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i+1][w+1].rgbtBlue;
                    int rightBottomBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i+1][w+1].rgbtGreen;
                    
                    totalRed = totalRed + rightBottomBoxRed; 
                    totalBlue = totalBlue + rightBottomBoxBlue;
                    totalGreen = totalGreen + rightBottomBoxGreen;
                    counter++; 
                }
                
                int bottomBoxRed = arrayCopy[i+1][w].rgbtRed;
                int bottomBoxBlue = arrayCopy[i+1][w].rgbtBlue;
                int bottomBoxGreen = arrayCopy[i+1][w].rgbtGreen;
                counter++;
                
                totalRed = totalRed + bottomBoxRed; 
                totalBlue = totalBlue + bottomBoxBlue;
                totalGreen = totalGreen + bottomBoxGreen;
                
            }
            
            
            float averageRed = totalRed / (float) counter; 
            float averageBlue = totalBlue / (float) counter;
            float averageGreen = totalGreen / (float) counter;
            
        
            
            image[i][w].rgbtRed = (int) roundf(averageRed); 
            image[i][w].rgbtBlue = (int) roundf(averageBlue);
            image[i][w].rgbtGreen = (int) roundf(averageGreen);
                
            //printf("%i\n", (int) roundf(averageRed));
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
original image
[image]
my image output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first failed rest result (by the way, please avoid putting images of text in your questions), you're supposed to calculate a value of 127 for the red component of the middle pixel. You calculated 128.

The red components of the nine pixels in this image are as follows:

```
 10  40  70
110 120 130
200 220 240
```

If, as you claim at the top of your question, you're supposed to be calculating the average of the eight pixels surrounding the centre pixel, then you'll get a value of (10+40+70+110+130+200+220+240)/8, which is equal to 127.5. The `roundf()` function rounds up half-way cases away from zero, so by the look of things, you obtained the correct answer of 128 as the result.

However, I suspect you're actually supposed to calculate the average of all nine pixels, including the centre pixel. In this case, the result would be (10+40+70+110+120+130+200+220+240)/9, which `roundf()` will round up from 126.67 to 127.

So I think all you're doing wrong is forgetting to include the pixel at `arrayCopy[i][w]` in your calculation.

I should also point out that your code is very [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). It's easy to lose track of what's going on in code like this, and debugging can be difficult. Perhaps consider using an inner loop to scan each block of (up to) nine pixels. Something like this, perhaps (caveat: I haven't tested this at all):

```
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
            int counter = 0;
            int totalr=0, totalg=0, totalb=0;
            for (int dx=-1; dx<=1; dx++) {
                if (x+dx < 0 || x+dx >= width) continue;
                for (int dy=-1; dy<=1; dy++) {
                    if (y+dy >=0 && y+dy < height) {
                        totalr += image[y+dy][x+dx].rgbtRed;
                        totalg += image[y+dy][x+dx].rgbtGreen;
                        totalb += image[y+dy][x+dx].rgbtBlue;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            result[y][x].rgbtRed = roundf(totalr / (float)counter);
            result[y][x].rgbtGreen = roundf(totalg / (float)counter);
            result[y][x].rgbtBlue = roundf(totalb / (float)counter);
        }
    }
```